# Enhancement and MPP of a basic Al-air battery with saline electrolyte

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry, energy-harvesting, mppt

I created a simple Al-air battery in oceans using Aluminum and graphite electrodes with ocean water as the electrolyte. There is no electrical separation between the electrodes due to design constraints (the electrodes do not physically touch each other but are present in the same saline solution)

The open-circuit voltage of the system is ~1.1V and the short circuit current (max) is approximately 30 mA. When a load is added, the voltage drops and current flows through the load. The current, however, decreases slowly while the voltage increases slowly if sufficient water flow is absent. Thus, measuring the maximum power point (MPP) of the system is quite difficult due to variable parameter values.

What is the usual MPP of such batteries? I wanted to find this out because I am using a BQ25570 energy harvesting IC for power management and it has MPPT options.

Also, if I use Al-Zn alloy instead of Al for the anode and activated carbon fabric with MnO2 electrocatalyst at the cathode, will this improve electrochemical performance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enhancement and MPP of a basic Al-air battery with saline electrolyte](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520762/enhancement-and-mpp-of-a-basic-al-air-battery-with-saline-electrolyte)

Comment: @rdtsc sorry I posted twice by mistake. I deleted that post.

Comment: _"What is the usual MPP of such batteries?"_ - I can't find any commercial examples of such a battery, so the answer may be that there is no 'usual'. Usually a battery is not run at the MPP anyway, since it wastes energy.